# Adjust indentation of the subsequent lines in description environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, enumitem

How do I control the indentation of subsequent lines without affecting the other settings? That is, I want the spacing of the first three components to remain as is, but when the content of the line spills onto the second line, the second line should be indented further.

A *simple* solution would be to make the second and third items be part of the label, but would prefer not to have to resort to that.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[
    leftmargin=!, 
    labelwidth=!,
    labelsep=5pt,
    parsep=0pt, 
    itemsep=0pt,
    itemindent=0pt,
    ]\RaggedRight
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI 1-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [XYZ] ABC KYJ efp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfv-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
\end{description}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question. You can change `leftmargin` and `itemindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[
    leftmargin=40pt, 
    labelwidth=!,
    labelsep=5pt,
    parsep=0pt, 
    itemsep=0pt,
    itemindent=-10pt,
    ]\RaggedRight
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI 1-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [XYZ] ABC KYJ efp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfv-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
\end{description}

\begin{description}[
    leftmargin=30pt, 
    labelwidth=!,
    labelsep=5pt,
    parsep=0pt, 
    itemsep=0pt,
    itemindent=-10pt,
    ]\RaggedRight
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [ABC] DEF GHI 1-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
    \item [XYZ] ABC KYJ efp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfv-abcpdefp-higj-akdf-dggg-vfve-vfvervr-vdfvfdv-dfvdfvfdv-dvfvd
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, you understood it just fine. I just didn't think of having a negative `itemident`.